# How to use pandas .replace() with list of regexs while honoring list order?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have 2 dataframes: one (`A`) with some whitelist hostnames in regex form (ie `(.*)microsoft.com`, `(*.)go.microsoft.com`...) and another (`B`) with actual full hostnames of sites.  I want to add a new column to this 2nd dataframe with the regex text of the Whitelist (1st) dataframe.  However, it appears that Pandas' `.replace()` method doesn't care about what order items are in for its `to_replace` and `value` args.

My data looks like this:

```
In [1] A
Out[1]: 
                                  wildcards  \
42   (.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com   
35    (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com   
40      (.*)settings-win.data.microsoft.com   
43            (.*)smartscreen.microsoft.com   
39             (.*).playready.microsoft.com   
38                     (.*)go.microsoft.com   
240                     (.*)i.microsoft.com   
238                       (.*)microsoft.com   
                                                 regex  
42   re.compile('^(.*)activation.playready.microsof...  
35   re.compile('^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft...  
40   re.compile('^(.*)settings-win.data.microsoft.c...  
43       re.compile('^(.*)smartscreen.microsoft.com$')  
39        re.compile('^(.*).playready.microsoft.com$')  
38                re.compile('^(.*)go.microsoft.com$')  
240                re.compile('^(.*)i.microsoft.com$')  
238                  re.compile('^(.*)microsoft.com$')  


In [2] B.head()
Out[2]: 
                       server_hostname
146     mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com
205    settings-win.data.microsoft.com
341      nav.smartscreen.microsoft.com
406  v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
667                  www.microsoft.com
```

Notice that `A` has a column of compiled regexes in similar form to the `wildcards` column. I want to add a `wildcard` column to `B` like this:

`B.loc[:,'wildcards'] = B['server_hostname'].replace(A['regex'].tolist(), A['wildcards'].tolist())`

But the problem is, all of `B`'s wildcard values become `(.*)microsoft.com`.  This happens no matter the order of `A`'s wildcard values.  It appears `.replace()` aims to use the `to_replace` regex's by shortest value first rather than the order provided.

How can I provide a list of `to_replace` values so that I ultimately get the most details hostname `wildcards` value associated with `B`'s `server_hostname` values?

Comment: Can you few sample values? Also is the count of `B` rows same as `A`?

Comment: Can you slice the strings?

Comment: Slicing strings is fine with me @U10-Forward.   And @Tarun Lalwani,  the counts of B and A are different.  `A` is a list of all whitelisted wildcards, and `B` is a table of many URL on server_hostnames, some of which may be on (sub)domains in the `wildcard` list in A.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers use `apply()` which is known to be slower than built-in vector function solutions.  My hope in using `.replace()` was that it would be fast since it is such a built in vector function.  @vlemaistre's answer was the only one to not use `.apply()` as is my solution here, which instead of compiling each wildcard into a regex, it treats it as a right-hand substring to use logic: "If `server_hostname` ends with `wildcard`, then it's a match".  So long as I sort my wildcards by length, then it works just fine.

My function which does this is:

```
def match_to_whitelist(accepts_df, whitelist_df):
    """ Adds `whitelists` column to accepts_df showing which (if any) whitelist entry it matches with """
    accepts_df.loc[:, 'wildcards'] = None
    for wildcard in whitelist_df['wildcards']:
        accepts_df.loc[(accepts_df['wildcards'].isnull()) & (
            accepts_df['server_hostname'].str.endswith(wildcard)), 'wildcards'] = wildcard
    rows_matched = len(accepts_df['wildcards'].notnull())
matched {rows_matched}")
    return accepts_df
```

Here, `accepts_df` is like `B` from before, and `whitelist_df` is like `A` before, but with 2 differences:

1. no `regex` column
2. the `wildcards` values are no longer in glob/regex format (ie "(.*)microsoft.com" becomes "microsoft.com"

To benchmark answers on my machine, I'll use mine as a baseline, taking 27secs to process 100k `accepts_df` rows with 400 `whitelist_df` rows.  Using the same dataset, here are the times for other solutions (i was lazy: if they didn't run out the gate, I didn't debug much to find out):

- @vlemaistre - List Comprehension with vector functions: 193sec
- @user214 - SequenceMatcher: 234sec
- @aws_apprentice - Compare RE search result lengths: 24sec
- @fpersyn - First match (will be best match if `A` is sorted): over 6mins, so quit...
- @Andy Hayden - `lastgroup`: didn't test because I can't (quickly) build a long RE programatically.
- @capelastegui - `Series.str.match()`: Error: "pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Ultimately, none of our answers say how to use `.replace()` as desired, so for the time being, I'll leave this unanswered for a few weeks in case someone can provide an answer to better use `.replace()`, or at least some other fast vector-based solution.  Until then, I'll keep with what I have, or maybe use aws_apprentice's after I verify results.

**EDIT**
I improved my matcher by adding a "domain" column to both DFs, which consists of the last 2 parts of each wildcard/server_hostname (ie www.microsoft.com becomes "microsoft.com").  I then used `groupby('domain')` on both DFs, iterated through the whitelist groups of domains, fetched the same domain-group from the server_hostname DF (B) and did my matching just using the subset of wildcards/server_hostnames from each group.  This cut my processing time to match in half.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using a double list comprehension and the `re.sub()` function :

```
import re

A = pd.DataFrame({'wildcards' : ['(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)i.microsoft.com', '(.*)microsoft.com'],
                  'regex' : [re.compile('^(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com$'),
                             re.compile('^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)i.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)microsoft.com$')]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'server_hostname' : ['v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                       'www.microsoft.com']})
# For each server_hostname we try each regex and keep the longest matching one
B['wildcards'] = [max([re.sub(to_replace, value, x) for to_replace, value
                       in A[['regex', 'wildcards']].values
                       if re.sub(to_replace, value, x)!=x], key=len) 
                  for x in B['server_hostname']]
```

---

```
Output : 
                     server_hostname                              wildcards
0  v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
1                  www.microsoft.com                      (.*)microsoft.com
```

Comment: I like this answer since it doesn't use `apply()`.  However, it ends up being slower than other methods.   I'll post my own answer, which tests the right portion of a string to see if the wildcard is in the server_hostname.  On a dataset of ~100k rows with server_hostnames, and 400 wildcards to match, my method took 27 secs where this method took 193.  I'll benchmark other answers to select which one I think is the best solution.  Thanks for dodging `apply()` since that's usually slow!

Answer (score 0):

One alternate way would be to use [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) and [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects).

Taken data from the answer given by @vlemaistre

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import pandas as pd
import re

A = pd.DataFrame({'wildcards' : ['(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)i.microsoft.com', '(.*)microsoft.com'],
                  'regex' : [re.compile('^(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com$'),
                             re.compile('^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)i.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)microsoft.com$')]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'server_hostname' : ['v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                       'www.microsoft.com', 'www.i.microsoft.com']})

def regex_match(x):
    match = None
    ratio = 0
    for w, r in A[['wildcards', 'regex']].to_numpy():
        if re.match(r, x) is not None:
            pct = SequenceMatcher(None, w, x).ratio()
            if ratio < pct: ratio = pct; match = w
    return match

B['wildcards'] = B.server_hostname.apply(regex_match)

# print(B.wildcards)
0    (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
1                        (.*)microsoft.com
2                      (.*)i.microsoft.com
Name: server_hostname, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `apply`. There is no *pure* `pandas` way to do this as far as I know. I also borrowed the data that [@vlemaistre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11492024/vlemaistre) provided.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'wildcards' : ['(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)i.microsoft.com', '(.*)microsoft.com'],
                  'regex' : [re.compile('^(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com$'),
                             re.compile('^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)i.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)microsoft.com$')]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'server_hostname' : ['v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                       'www.microsoft.com']})

pats = set(A.regex)

def max_match(hostname):
    d = {}
    for pat in pats:
        maybe_result = pat.search(hostname)
        if maybe_result:
            p = pat.pattern
            d[len(p)] = p
    return d.get(max([*d]))

B['wildcards'] = B['server_hostname'].apply(max_match)

                     server_hostname                                wildcards
0  v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  ^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com$
1                  www.microsoft.com                      ^(.*)microsoft.com$
```

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) describes the `.replace()` method as:

> Values of the DataFrame are replaced with other values dynamically. This differs from updating with .loc or .iloc, which require you to specify a location to update with some value.

This implies that the method will iterate over all cells in the dataframe and replace what it can for each query provided in the `to_replace` argument. A quick example to demonstrate this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','c'],'B':['b','d']})
df.replace(['a','b'],['b','c'])

Output:
    A   B
0   c   c
1   c   d
```

In your example, each regex rule overwrites previous replacements when there is a new match, which is how you end up with a vector of `(.*)microsoft.com` results.

You could use the `.apply()` method instead. For instance, by sorting your whitelist (A) descending by length, iterate over each row of your value DataFrame (B) and return each first match:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# Using the definitions for A and B from your question, 
# where A is sorted descending by length.

def first_match(x):
    for index, row in A.iterrows():
        if bool(re.search(row['wildcards'], x['server_hostname'])) is True:
            return row['wildcards']
B['wildcards'] = B.apply(first_match, axis=1)
B

Output:
    server_hostname                     wildcards
0   mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com      (.*)microsoft.com
1   settings-win.data.microsoft.com     (.*)settings-win.data.microsoft.com
2   nav.smartscreen.microsoft.com       (.*)smartscreen.microsoft.com
3   v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com   (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
4   www.microsoft.com                   (.*)microsoft.com
```

It might also be worth reading up on the [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) pattern for more advanced strategies. I hope that helps.

Comment: Note that my `.replace()` example above does not hold when replacing integers using lists. See the "List-like to_replace" examples in the pandas docs (link above).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative tack, which unfortunately still needs an apply, is to use [`lastgroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.lastgroup). This entails compiling a single regex and then looking up the name of the matched group (row):

```
In [11]: regex = re.compile("|".join([f"(?P<i{i}>{regex})" for i, regex in s["wildcards"].items()]))

In [12]: regex
Out[12]:
re.compile(r'(?P<i42>(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com)|(?P<i35>(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com)|(?P<i40>(.*)settings-win.data.microsoft.com)|(?P<i43>(.*)smartscreen.microsoft.com)|(?P<i39>(.*).playready.microsoft.com)|(?P<i38>(.*)go.microsoft.com)|(?P<i240>(.*)i.microsoft.com)|(?P<i238>(.*)microsoft.com)',
re.UNICODE)

In [13]: B.server_hostname.apply(lambda s: int(re.match(regex, s).lastgroup[1:]))
Out[13]:
146    238
205     40
341     43
406     35
667    238
Name: server_hostname, dtype: int64

In [14]: B.server_hostname.apply(lambda s: int(re.match(regex, s).lastgroup[1:])).map(s.wildcards)
Out[14]:
146                        (.*)microsoft.com
205      (.*)settings-win.data.microsoft.com
341            (.*)smartscreen.microsoft.com
406    (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
667                        (.*)microsoft.com
Name: server_hostname, dtype: object
```

This attribute isn't exposed by pandas (but it might be possible to do something clever with the internals)...

Answer (score 0):

The purest pandas approach that I could find involves running `Series.str.match()` on B.server_hostname for each regex, then taking the first match from each column with `idxmax()`.

```py
# Create input data
A = pd.DataFrame({'wildcards' : ['(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                 '(.*)i.microsoft.com', '(.*)microsoft.com'],
                  'regex' : [re.compile('^(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com$'),
                             re.compile('^(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)i.microsoft.com$'), 
                             re.compile('^(.*)microsoft.com$')]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'server_hostname' : ['v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com',
                                       'www.microsoft.com']})

# Ensure B has a unique index
B = B.reset_index(drop=True)

# Check which regexes match each hostname
df_match = A.regex.apply(lambda x: B.server_hostname.str.match(x))
df_match.index= A.wildcards
df_match.columns=B.server_hostname

# Get first match for each hostname
df_first_match = df_match.idxmax().rename('wildcards').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
print(df_match)
print(df_first_match)

server_hostname                         v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  www.microsoft.com
wildcards                                                                                   
(.*)activation.playready.microsoft.com                              False              False
(.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com                                True              False
(.*)i.microsoft.com                                                 False              False
(.*)microsoft.com                                                    True               True

                     server_hostname                              wildcards
0  v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  (.*)v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
1                  www.microsoft.com                      (.*)microsoft.com
```

That said, this seems to be a bit slower than other solutions posted earlier.

Comment: @hamx0r got the following error when running this solution: `Error: "pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"` . I can reproduce this by passing an input B dataframe with duplicate values in the index, e.g. `B=pd.concat([B,B])` . A possible fix for this would be `B = B.reset_index(drop=True)`.